# WiX Conditional Registry Entries

Tags: wix, windows-installer, setup-project, wix3.7

I'm working on my first ever WiX project and I'm having a tough time getting some registry entries to work properly.

My requirements are, to have an option in the setup to choose whether the software will be installed on a desktop computer, or on an aircraft. Since there isn't really any way to detect it automatically, I've created an additional UI screen with some radio buttons. (this is in a separate file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <UI>
            <Dialog Id="AircraftDesktopDlg_Custom"
                    Width="370"
                    Height="270"
                    Title="!(loc.InstallDirDlg_Title)">
                <Control Type="RadioButtonGroup"
                         Property="InstallType_Prop"
                         Id="InstallType"
                         Width="200"
                         Height="42"
                         X="20"
                         Y="110">
                    <RadioButtonGroup Property="InstallType_Prop">
                        <RadioButton Text="Aircraft"
                                     Height="17"
                                     Value="0"
                                     Width="50"
                                     X="0"
                                     Y="0" />
                        <RadioButton Text="Desktop"
                                     Height="17"
                                     Value="1"
                                     Width="200"
                                     X="0"
                                     Y="20" />
                    </RadioButtonGroup>
                </Control>
            </Dialog>
        </UI>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

**Code Listing 1 - Radio Buttons**

Then, over in my main Product.wxs file, I have the following.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product>
    <Property Id="InstallType_Prop"
              Value="0"/>
    .
    .
    .
    <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
        <Component Id="AircraftRegistryEntries"
                   Guid="E251C37B-2A4F-46D4-8E9F-24C66FB107E9">
            <Condition>InstallType_Prop = 0</Condition>
            <RegistryKey Root="HKLM"
                         Key="Software\Company\Product\v1.0"
                         Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
                <RegistryValue Type="integer"
                               Name="OfflineMode"
                               Value="0"/>
                <RegistryValue Type="integer"
                               Name="Simulator"
                               Value="0"/>
            </RegistryKey>
        </Component>
        <Component Id="DesktopRegistryEntries"
                   Guid="CACDBBB6-BCAA-4B71-92BE-C762325580A3">
            <Condition>InstallType_Prop = 1</Condition>
            <RegistryKey Root="HKLM"
                         Key="Software\Company\Product\v1.0"
                         Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
                <RegistryValue Type="integer"
                               Name="OfflineMode"
                               Value="1"/>
                <RegistryValue Type="integer"
                               Name="Simulator"
                               Value="0"/>
            </RegistryKey>
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
    .
    .
    .
    <Feature Id='Complete'
             Level='1'>
        <ComponentRef Id='AircraftRegistryEntries'/>
        <ComponentRef Id='DesktopRegistryEntries'/>
    </Feature>
</Product>
</Wix>
```

**Code Listing 2 - Property and Registry Entry**

So as you can see, the radio button is tied to the InstallType_Prop.

What I am trying to accomplish is to install the appropriate registry entry depending on which radio button is selected. I inserted those conditions in the registry components, but they don't seem to be doing anything.

I don't even really have to do it this way - I just need OfflineMode to be set to 1 if Desktop is selected, and set to 0 if Aircraft is selected.

I'm at a loss right now, and I think the solution lies somewhere with a custom action or with the order in which the conditions are evaluated, but I'm not entirely sure.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you find a solution? I have a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

IMO the usual way to do this is to group the various components into (say) two features, one per type of system, then the users see the standard feature tree where they choose the appropriate one. In the case of registry entries, you'd have a component (for the registry entry) for each type of install, one would be in one feature, the other in the other.